# How to install the HL 5470DW driver

Tags: installation, drivers, printing

there are two drivers on the website:

http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public/us/us/en/dlf/download_index.html?reg=us&c=us&lang=en&prod=hl5470dw_us_eu_as&dlid=&flang=English&os=128&type2=-1

The lpr driver and the cups wrapper driver. which to choose?

And what is the step by step to install it?

im running ubuntu 13.04 32 bit

Answer (score 0):

I've always used cups for printing.

```
sudo aa-complain cupsd
sudo mkdir /usr/share/cups/model

**ABOVE IS FOR PREREQUISITES**
```

Download the LPR **AND** CUPS driver.

Follow instructions located on CUPS driver download page.

*HINTS:*

```
 sudo su - #Gives you root.
 You are using dpkg.
```

[Instructions I was looking at.](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public/us/us/en/dlf/dlf/000000/006000/dlf006029.html?reg=us&c=us&lang=en&prod=hl5470dw_us_eu_as&type2=91&os=128&flang=4&dlid=dlf006029)

[Prereq source (Look for "(2)")](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/before.html#002)

Answer (score 0):

Download To your downloads directory both the LPR and CUPS Printer Driver/Linux (deb) files from the Brother website;

http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public/us/us/en/dlf/download_index.html?reg=us&c=us&lang=en&prod=hl5470dw_us_eu_as&dlid=&flang=English&os=128&type2=-1

open your terminal app and run:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

then install each driver package with:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all hl5470dwcupswrapper-3.0.0-1.i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-all hl5470dwlpr-3.0.0-1.i386.deb
```

your HL-540 printer should now appear in your system settings - printer configuration GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I have two brother printers - one about 7 years old, and another that I bought this year.  The brother drivers work great from windows.  But they leave something to be desired if you're running Linux.  I have nothing to add for the Brother drivers specifically, but if you get frustrated, I'd recommend that you use the HP PCL 6 drivers instead.  Brother printers can use this driver and it seems to be a lot more stable.

Specifically, the Brother driver for Linux always seemed to have an issue with printing postscript or PDF.  I spent some time trying to fix it, but threw up my hands after expending far too much time on it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem getting the Brother drivers to work on Ubuntu 13.10 (saucy).  What I found was that my box (System 76 Galago Ultrpro) is a 64 bit system (amd64) but the Brother drivers are 32 bit (x86).

I downloaded the GNU C compiler multilib utilities [gcc-4.*n*-multilib] and the drivers worked fine.  If your machine is 64 bit arch you might want to give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this address: http://support.brother.com/g/b/producttop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl5470dw_us_eu_as

Select LINUX and DEB as the OS and package types.  Download the load tool into your Downloads folder.

Uncompress the tool in the Downloads folder by opening it through the file manager and extracting the tool.

Open a Terminal window.

- Change the permissions to allow execution `chmod +x ./linux-brprinter-installer*`
- Execute the driver tool `sudo ./linux-brprinter-installer*`
- Perform the install (you will be prompted for the brother printer type)
  Do not specify the URI

Open the Printer dialog under settings or through dash type printer
Select the brother printer
Change the destination which is defaulted to `USB://` to `ipp://<insert ip address of printer`

To find the IP address of the printer, go to the printer and through the menu select to print the printer settings.

Good luck!